# Adding .dSYM files for compiled frameworks and sending them to App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, symbolicatecrash, dsym

We are submitting an app with a compiled framework to the App Store. The dSYM file for the framework is available before the app is built in Xcode. Does it make sense to copy the dSYM file into the archive (via a build step) before it is uploaded to Apple? Will Apple use the extra dSYM file automatically, e.g. will the symbolication of the framework work for instance with TestFlight?

And more importantly, will the dSYM *not* be shipped to the users? (If someone could provide a link that states that the dSYMS are stripped by Apple that would be great, too.)

Answer (score 0):

You can read about dSYMs:

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html
- https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/missing-dsyms.html

You can try to put dSYM files into dSYM folder inside archive and apple will use it on TestFlight.

You can also use crashlytics service and upload dSYMs anytime.
You can symbolicate crash logs by your own, if you have dSYM files locally.

Appstore and TF are not shipping dSYMs within the apps. dSYMs are embedded in dev builds only.